# Analogue of ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING at clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

Transfering code on Postgres to Clickhouse. Need to updating 1 table every week. At Postgres looks like ([ON CONFLICT Clause](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/sql-insert.html#SQL-ON-CONFLICT)):

```
INSERT INTO ulog
(
    id,
    us_id,
    inst_date,
    st_change_date,
    prev_st,
    st,
    update_date
)
select id
    , us_id
    , inst_date
    , case 
        when st= 1 then inst_date
        when st= 2 then active_date
        when st= 0 then  dor_date 
        when st= -1 then ch_date 
        when st= 3 then ret_date 
        else today()
        end as st_change_date
    , prev_st
    , st
    , now()
from user_st
where coalesce(st, -99) != coalesce(prev_st, -99)
ON CONFLICT (
    id,
    us_id,
    st_change_date
    )
DO NOTHING
;
```

How I can rewrite this query on ClickHouse?

I tried some separate queries for different combinations of "st" and "st_prev", for example

```sql
INSERT INTO ulog 
( id, us_id, inst_date, st_change_date, prev_st, st, update_date ) 
select id 
, us_id 
, inst_date 
, case 
    when st= 1 then inst_date 
    when st= 2 then active_date 
    when st= 0 then dor_date 
    when st= -1 then ch_date 
    when st= 3 then ret_date 
    else today() end as st_change_date 
, prev_st
, st
, today() from user_st where status=1 and prev_st=1
```

Comment: What have you tried? (As a starting point.)

Comment: Add for question first step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CH does not support `ON CONFLICT` and will never support. It's against CH (OLAP) db nature. CH just append rows (writes a new part) and could not check rows by key (it will slow down insert to 100000 times).

```
INSERT INTO ulog
(
    id,
    us_id,
    inst_date,
    st_change_date,
    prev_st,
    st,
    update_date
)
select id
    , us_id
    , inst_date
    , case 
        when st= 1 then inst_date
        when st= 2 then active_date
        when st= 0 then  dor_date 
        when st= -1 then ch_date 
        when st= 3 then ret_date 
        else today()
        end as st_change_date
    , prev_st
    , st
    , now()
from user_st
where coalesce(st, -99) != coalesce(prev_st, -99)
   and (id, us_id,st_change_date) not in (select id, us_id,st_change_date from ulog);
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [ReplacingMergeTree](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table-engines/mergetree-family/replacingmergetree/)-engine to ignore subsequent rows with the same key.

Take into account this way doesn’t guarantee the absence of duplicates.

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ulog
(
  st_change_date DateTime,
  id Int32,
  us_id Int32,
  inst_date DateTime,
  prev_st Int32,
  st Int32,
  update_date DateTime,
  version UInt32 MATERIALIZED toUInt32(now() - toDateTime('2105-12-31 23:59:59'))
)
Engine = ReplacingMergeTree(version)
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(st_change_date)
ORDER BY (st_change_date, id, us_id)
```

```sql
INSERT INTO ulog VALUES
('2020-09-01 10:00:00', 111, 345, now(), 11, 12, now()),

('2020-09-01 10:00:00', 222, 345, now(), 11, 12, now()),
('2020-09-01 10:00:01', 222, 345, now(), 11, 12, now()),

('2020-09-01 10:00:00', 333, 345, now(), 11, 12, now()),
('2020-09-01 10:00:01', 333, 345, now(), 11, 12, now());

INSERT INTO ulog VALUES
('2020-09-01 10:00:00', 111, 345, now(), 22, 33, now());

INSERT INTO ulog VALUES
('2020-09-01 10:00:00', 111, 345, now(), 33, 44, now());
```

```sql
SELECT *, version FROM ulog
/*
┌──────st_change_date─┬──id─┬─us_id─┬───────────inst_date─┬─prev_st─┬─st─┬─────────update_date─┬────version─┐
│ 2020-09-01 10:00:00 │ 111 │   345 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │      11 │ 12 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │ 1603329132 │
│ 2020-09-01 10:00:00 │ 222 │   345 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │      11 │ 12 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │ 1603329132 │
│ 2020-09-01 10:00:00 │ 333 │   345 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │      11 │ 12 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │ 1603329132 │
│ 2020-09-01 10:00:01 │ 222 │   345 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │      11 │ 12 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │ 1603329132 │
│ 2020-09-01 10:00:01 │ 333 │   345 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │      11 │ 12 │ 2020-09-14 18:43:55 │ 1603329132 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴───────┴─────────────────────┴─────────┴────┴─────────────────────┴────────────┘
*/
```